# AuthenticationError Google Dive API client_secrets.json

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-authentication

**Set-up**

I have a local folder – `access_google_drive` – which contains the .py script used to access my Google Drive account via the Google Drive API.

The script looks like this,

```
def connect_google_drive_api():
    
    import os   
        
    # use Gdrive API to access Google Drive
    os.chdir('/Users/my/fol/ders/access_google_drive')
    from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
    from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
    
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # client_secrets.json need to be in the same directory as the script
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    
    return drive
```

In the `access_google_drive` I also have the `client_secrets.json` file.

---

**Issue**

This set-up worked fine, until yesterday. Since yesterday, I see the following error,

```
Failed to find "code" in the query parameters of the redirect.
Try command-line authentication
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-48c5ad9148cf>", line 2, in <module>
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # client_secrets.json need to be in the same directory as the script

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 115, in _decorated
    code = decoratee(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 241, in LocalWebserverAuth
    raise AuthenticationError('No code found in redirect')

AuthenticationError: No code found in redirect
```

---

**Question**

I have no idea why I'm seeing this error. Both script and file are in the same folder. I haven't edited the script nor the .json.

Did I miss an update? Are the stars not aligned?

Who can help me out?

Comment: I didn't misspell the `client_secrets.json` file name :-)

Comment: In your situation, is `settings.yaml` used?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for thinking with me. I'm afraid I'm not even sure what that is. Should I use it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `settings.yaml`, you can see it at https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html?highlight=yaml