# PyDrive 2.0 – AuthenticationError: No code found in redirect

Tags: python, google-drive-api, anaconda, google-authentication, pydrive

**Set-up**

I'm using PyDrive 2.0 to connect to the Google Drive API.

```
def connect_google_drive_api():
    
    import os   
        
    # use Gdrive API to access Google Drive
    os.chdir('/Users/my/fol/ders/access_google_drive')
    from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
    from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
    
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # client_secrets.json need to be in the same directory as the script
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    
    return drive
```

The working directory `/Users/mypath/access_google_drive` contains the `client_secrets.json`, which looks like,

```
{"web":{"client_id":"xxx","project_id":"invoice-creation-290413","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"xxx","redirect_uris":["http://localhost:8080/"],"javascript_origins":["http://localhost:8080"]}}
```

where I replaced the real `client_id` and `client_secret` with `xxx`.

---

**Issue**

When the browser (Safari 14.0) shows `Gdrive api link wants to access your Google Account` and I click `Allow`, the process seems to be stuck.

After 20 seconds or so, the following error is shown,

```
Failed to find "code" in the query parameters of the redirect.
Try command-line authentication
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-36-792f41ab7318>", line 1, in <module>
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive2/auth.py", line 125, in _decorated
    code = decoratee(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive2/auth.py", line 273, in LocalWebserverAuth
    raise AuthenticationError("No code found in redirect")

AuthenticationError: No code found in redirect
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: I've managed to connect using the quickstart.py set-up of Google, and adjusting the code a little. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956706/google-drive-api-quickstart-py-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch. But I'd love to hear a solution to connect via PyDrive

Comment: Although I asked at [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63940770/7108653), in your situation, is `settings.yaml` used? Or you are directly using `client_secrets.json`? Because unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `AuthenticationError: No code found in redirect`. Or, can I ask you about the flow for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I'm not using `settings.yaml`. I have the `client_secrets.json` in the working directory.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tested your situation using `client_secrets.json` without using `settings.yaml`. But unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In my environment, no error occurs using `client_secrets.json` with `"redirect_uris":["http://localhost:8080/"],"javascript_origins":["http://localhost:8080"]`. So can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: @Tanaike, I've edited the code in the question to adjust for the version I use. Namely, I'm calling the connection into another script, say script `x.py`. I had set both the working directory in `x.py` and the code above. It seems that all I needed to do was remove the `os.chdir('/Users/my/fol/ders/access_google_drive')` line from the code above.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was importing `connect_google_drive_api()` into another script, say script `x.py`.

Both the `connect_google_drive_api()` function and `x.py` had the line `os.chdir('/Users/my/fol/ders/access_google_drive')` to set the working directory to where the `client_secrets.json` was.

With the following code, I actually make a connection without any issue,

```
def connect_google_drive_api():
        
    # use Gdrive API to access Google Drive
    from pydrive2.auth import GoogleAuth
    from pydrive2.drive import GoogleDrive
    
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # client_secrets.json need to be in the same directory as the script    
    
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    
    return drive
```

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to run this code from a Jupiter notebook. I was able to successfully authenticate when I switched browsers from Safari(14.0.1) to Chrome(87.0.4280.88)